# Как можно удалять запятые в двумерном массиве в TeleBot?

Tags: python

Как можно удалить запятые и [] при выводе двумерного массива сообщением в
телеграмме? Библиотека PyTelegramBotApi

Comment: а сам массив как выглядит?

Comment: a = [ [ 1, 2 ,3 ,4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать распаковку массива со звёздочкой

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
for i in a:
    print(*i)
```

Вывод:

```
1 2 3

4 5 6
```

Ну насчёт именно сообщений в телеграме не знаю

Comment: Здесь цикл проходит по массиву и распаковывает вложенные массивы

Comment: Спасибо за данное решение, но у меня возникли проблемы именно с выводом в телегу, в консоли никаких проблем нет.